# I am trying to create a box in React, and it is not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Here is my code:

```
   class Landing extends Component {
  state = {
    box: " width: 300px , height: 100px, border: 1px solid blue; ",
  };


  render() {
    return <div className={this.state.box}>Hello</div>;
  }
}
```

The idea is that "Hello" should be inside a box.

Instead, what I am getting is a web page with no box, just a hello.

Please help.

Comment: So, `width: 300px , height: 100px, border: 1px solid blue;` are the names of the classes, as you are using `className={this.state.box}` ?

Comment: You should move the `state.box` into a CSS/LESS file and use className instead. Also, its better to have className sent in props as it will not change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `className` to `style` and turn `box` in to a real object.

```
class Landing extends Component {
  state = {
    box: {width: '300px', height: '100px', border: '1px solid blue'},
  };


  render() {
    return <div style={this.state.box}>Hello</div>;
  }
}
```